# View within a view Layout issue

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I want to display a view within a view. This works as I want but I'm having an issue with the layout of a table.

[image]

I want to move the table left so it is under the address button. I'm not quite sure why it is placed where it is. Here is my Reports View.

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Reports</h2>
    <br />
    <button id="address">Addresses</button>
<button id="Qualifications"> Qualifications</button>
    <style>
        #addrRpt { color: red;
                   background-color:blue;
                   margin-left:10px;
                   /*height: 250px;*/
                       
        }

    </style>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("address").onclick = function () { myFunction() };
        function myFunction() {

            $("#addrRpt").load("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("index", "Addresses")) ")
        }
    </script>


    @*<div class="row" >
        <div class="col" style="background-color:red">
            
            <div id="addrRpt">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>*@
    <div id="addrRpt"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the layout for the view to null resolved my issue.

Layout = null;